# cverror android assertion failed (scn == 3) Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to use adaptive thresholding on an image (Bitmap) I have in android which requires changing it into a Mat and then converting it to grayscale.

Below is my code starting with creating the bitmaps. They are named crop because I just cropped the photo right before this.

```
            Bitmap bmCrop = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
            Bitmap bmThreshed = null;
            /*
             * Initialize the Mats
             */
            Mat threshed = new Mat(bmCrop.getHeight(),bmCrop.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(4));//, new Scalar(4)
            //Mat crop = new Mat();
            Mat crop = new Mat(bmCrop.getHeight(),bmCrop.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1,new Scalar(4));//, new Scalar(4)
            /*
             * Convert the Mats to Grayscale
             */
            if(!threshed.empty())
                Imgproc.cvtColor(threshed, threshed, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,1);// CURRENTLY BREAKING HERE
            if(!crop.empty())
                Imgproc.cvtColor(crop, crop, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,1);         


            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmCrop, crop);

            // Mat src, Mat dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C
            Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(crop, threshed, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 8);

            Utils.matToBitmap(threshed, bmThreshed);
            bmThreshed = bmCrop;
```

It is currently breaking on the line "Imgproc.cvtColor(threshed, threshed, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,1)" where I attempt to cvtColor on the Mat.

Below is the output of LogCat:

```
05-28 11:25:21.172: E/cv::error()(32505): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3414
05-28 11:25:25.697: D/AndroidRuntime(32505): Shutting down VM
05-28 11:25:25.707: W/dalvikvm(32505): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414b1930)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505): CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3414: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function void cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505): ]
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor_0(Native Method)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.cvtColor(Imgproc.java:4017)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at com.activity.IMGP_Camera$1.onManagerConnected(IMGP_Camera.java:263)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1101)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1118)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-28 11:25:25.747: E/AndroidRuntime(32505):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my now working code.  The problem that I had was that I wasn't doing Utils.bitmapToMat() right after Initializing the Mats and before doing the cvtColor().

```
            /*
             * Initialize the bitmaps
             */
            Bitmap bmCrop = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
            Bitmap bmThreshed = bmCrop;
            /*
             * Initialize the Mats
             */
            Mat threshed = new Mat(bmCrop.getWidth(),bmCrop.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmCrop, threshed);

            Mat crop = new Mat(bmCrop.getWidth(),bmCrop.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmCrop, crop);
            /*
             * Convert the Mats to Grayscale
             */
            if(!threshed.empty())
                Imgproc.cvtColor(threshed, threshed, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            if(!crop.empty())
                Imgproc.cvtColor(crop, crop, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);           

            /*
             * Use Adaptive Thresholding on the grayscaled Mats
             * crop -> threshed
             * Mat src, Mat dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C
             */
            Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(crop, threshed, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 8);//15, 8 were original tests. Casey was 75,10

            Utils.matToBitmap(threshed, bmThreshed);
            bmThreshed = bmCrop;
```

Answer (score 5):

The assertion failure indicates that the input image to `cvtColor()` does not have either 3 or 4 channels. The problem is that you initialize `threshed` with type `CV_8UC1` (which is single-channel greyscale), but then call `cvtColor()` with the code `RGB2GRAY`, which expects a 3-channel RGB image.

You don't need to call `cvtColor()` on `threshed` at all, since it is already in greyscale. And, assuming your goal is to have the cropped image converted to greyscale, you will want to do the color conversion *after* you fill the `Mat` with data. Thus, the relevant portions of your code may look like this:

```
        Mat threshed = new Mat(bmCrop.getHeight(),bmCrop.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(4));//, new Scalar(4)
        //Mat crop = new Mat();
        Mat crop = new Mat(bmCrop.getHeight(),bmCrop.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1,new Scalar(4));//, new Scalar(4)

        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmCrop, crop);
        if(!crop.empty())
            Imgproc.cvtColor(crop, crop, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,1);
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not familiar with Java or the OpenCV Java API, so this code may need adjustment.

Comment: Thank you Aurelius!