# JavaCV Error in Android

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, javacv

It may be a previously asked related issue regarding  JavaCV on Android.My main objective is to apply grayscale/other image effect on video.

```
File sourceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "test.mp4");
    FFmpegFrameGrabber ffg = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(sourceFile);
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new     OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();


    try {
        ffg.start();
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            Log.d("JAVA_CV", "Counting . . . " + count);

            Frame original_frame = ffg.grab();

            if (original_frame == null) {
                Log.d("JAVA_CV", "original_frame is NULL at" + count);
                break;
            } else {
                Log.d("JAVA_CV", "original_frame is NOT_NULL at" + count);
                opencv_core.IplImage frame1 = converter.convert(original_frame);
                opencv_core.IplImage frame2 = opencv_core.IplImage.create(original_frame.imageWidth, original_frame.imageHeight, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);


                opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(frame1, frame2, opencv_imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

            }
            count++;
        }
    } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception fe) {
        fe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(fe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The exception has occured at line

```
 opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(frame1, frame2, opencv_imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Exception Stack is showing :

```
 OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in void    cv::cvtColor(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int), file /home/saudet/projects/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/opencv/cppbuild/android-arm/opencv-2.4.11/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3739
```

My research states that the issue is with channels and target color, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16801051/4840633).Please tell me the where can I get color-channel sheet ? or some other alternate solution.