# JavaCV on Android

Tags: android, javacv

How to use JavaCV on Android ? My main objective is to apply grayscale/other image effect on video.I am aware of ffmpeg to apply the commands but that requires NDK and I don't want to use NDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [JavaCV Error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917407/javacv-error-in-android) . But JavaCV or OpenCV are not meant for mobile resource platforms like Android.

We have only achieved result with ffmpeg on NDK.JavaCV was only successful upto a certain extent even that took huge amount of time.

Sometimes its intelligent to use a dedicated technology rather that pushing another technology to that field.